# how to Limit FileSize using AJAXFile Uploader in asp.net?

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-ajax, filesize

I have a AJAX File Uploader for Profile Image Upload. I want to restrict the user to upload image upto 102400 Bytes only.How to display javascript error message when file size exceeds.

Code:

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
    string workerfile = Session["LoginUserID"].ToString();
            string strFileName = string.Empty;
            string strFileType = string.Empty;
            string path = string.Empty;
            var folder = Server.MapPath("../worker/Uploads/" + workerfile);
    if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
                strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss");
                strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(e.FileName).ToString().ToLower();

                AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../worker/Uploads/" + Session["LoginUserID"] + "/" + workerfile + "_img" + strFileType));
            }
            else
            {

                strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss");
                strFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(e.FileName).ToString().ToLower();


                AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../worker/Uploads/" + Session["LoginUserID"] + "/" + workerfile + "_img" + strFileType));

            }
}
```

How to Do any Idea? 
Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to respond to the client with details on what went wrong server side - that is to say, there is no formal way to do so.  Here's an alternative:

1. Check the file size using AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.FileSize.  If it
   exceeds your maximum (it looks like you may be trying to limit to 1
   MB, the correct value is 1048576), set
   AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.PostedUrl = "Your file is too big, etc."
2. Set the OnClientUploadComplete property on your control to the name
       of a JS function that will either show the image if the file name
       string is formatted as such, or show a window with the error
       message.

It's a hack of course, but it'll work.